# Prim's Algorithm with matrices

Tags: c++, algorithm, prims-algorithm

I am trying to implement Prim's algorithm with C++ and matrices.

Here is my problem:

```
int node[] = {11, 11, 0, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11};
int nodeCon[8];

void generatePrims() {
    int cNode = 3;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {

        if (graph[cNode][i] != 0){

            if (node[i] > graph[cNode][i]) {
                node[i] = graph[cNode][i];
                nodeCon[i] = cNode;
                }
            }
        }
};
```

cNode is the starting node.

`graph[][]` is the 2d matrices that holds the connections.

`nodeCon[]` is the array that will hold the connections for the MST (which node is connected with other)

`node[]=` holds the cost-value for the nodeCon.

My question is how I am going to continue to the next hop? Let's say that I found the minimum connection and I will set the value `cNode= minConnection` how the loop is going to look? How I know that I had examine all the nodes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See if this helps: [Prim's Algorithm for Computing Minimum Spanning Trees](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/computersciencetheory/mst.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
int node[]={11,11,0,11,11,11,11,11};
int used[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
int nodeCon[8];

void generatePrims(){
   int cNode = 3;
   int next, min_now;
   for(int i=0; i<8; ++i) {
      used[cNode] = 1;
      min_now = MAX_INT;
      for(int i=1;i<=8;i++){
         if(!used[i]){ 
            if(node[i] > graph[cNode][i]){
               node[i] = graph[cNode][i];
               nodeCon[i]= cNode;
            }
            if(node[i] < min_now) {
               min_now = node[i];
               next = i;
            }  
         } 
      }
      cNode = next;
   }
};
```

Also worth noting: it will be faster if instead of array 'used' you will use a list of unused vertices.

Answer (score 0):

I can't currently comment on the previous answer (as I don't have enough reputation) so I will do it through another answer. Piotr solution is almost correct however I believe Prim's algorithm takes into account more than just the current node. An example can be seen here [Prim's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm#Example_run). What this essentially means is you need to check the path from nodes you have visited not just the most recent node.

This means you will need to store a vector containing the nodes you have visited and "for each" through them as opposed to just checking the paths from the last node you visited.

Answer (score 0):

The following site has the algorithm inplemented and a junit test class. So it should be what you are looking for. The unit test class has an actual matrix, of course. And the implementation class has the code.

http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/graph/mst